# How to handle multiple points at the same location in spatial interpolation?

Tags: interpolation, kriging, gis

I am new to the topic of spatial interpolation and would appreciate your opinion on a general question which has arisen.

Suppose I have a data set containing rental rates for different apartments in city A. In many cases, the data set contains multiple apartments in the same building. Moreover, the location is on building level. As a consequence, I have many data points at the same location.  How is this tackled when using spatial interpolation methods like inverse distance weighting or kriging? I would like to use as much information as possible but leaving the data set as it is, the distance between points at the same location will obviously be zero and hence causing problems. An idea that came to my mind was to deviate just a little bit for points at the same location to ease the problem.

Comment: It depends on the model and the method.  You offer two extreme examples: kriging (properly carried out) will automatically incorporate this variation (which can be treated as measurement variability or a nugget effect) while IDW can't handle it at all--and *ad hoc* declustering of the data will usually give useless results (or worse).  Arguably, if it's really rental rates you are interested in, you ought to handle that with something like a generalized linear model with spatially covarying parameters.

Comment: @ whuber Thank you for your valuable advice. Do you know any good literature for using generalized linear models with spatially covarying parameters? I guess this is what some people call regression kriging? Thank you

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geoRglm/index.html and the book that was written for it.

Comment: @ whuber Thank you very much. One more question, the problem with multiple observations at the same location remains the same, doesn't it? Hence, I cannot do kriging due to a covariance matrix which is singular.

Comment: Why would the covariance matrix be singular? I believe that if you model the variation due to multiple observations appropriately, you won't have that difficulty.

Comment: @whuber Please correct me when I am wrong but trying to do kriging in R using the gstat package (what I used before posting my question here), I ran into these problems and it seems to be common. See for example page 243 (bottom) of 
https://books.google.ch/books?id=v0eIU9ObJXgC&pg=PA244&lpg=PA244&dq=edzer+pebesma+kriging+singular+covariance+gstat&source=bl&ots=yDKFUuqWVl&sig=ACfU3U22ciZaH2l7lctR8ijbdgRsgPBx9Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5hZaeg_zgAhVRC-wKHUucD-wQ6AEwB3oECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=edzer%20pebesma%20kriging%20singular%20covariance%20gstat&f=false